# Observation Method for Poisson Process

Tags: simulation, poisson-distribution

I have about a year's worth of timestamps at which boxes exit a manufacturing production line. t<sub>i</sub> are the timestamps, where the first timestamp is t<sub>1</sub>, second timestamp is t<sub>2</sub>, etc. These can be anywhere from a few minutes apart to many hours apart. I would like to analyze the probability distribution for the number of boxes that exit the line in a 30-minute time interval (in order to make a simulation model for the boxes exiting the line). This sounds like a Poisson process.

I see 2 ways to extract the frequencies of box counts.

1. "Disjoint" windows. The first window is [t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>1</sub> + 30 minutes). Second window is [t<sub>1</sub> + 30 minutes, t<sub>1</sub> + 60 minutes). And so on. i.e. each window is 30 minutes long and is shifting by 30 minutes each time.
2. "Overlapping" windows. The first window is [t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>1</sub> + 30 minutes). Second window is [t<sub>1</sub> + 1 minute, t<sub>1</sub> + 31 minutes). And so on. i.e. each window is 30 minutes long and is shifting by 1 minute each time.

In both methods, count the number of boxes for each window. By the end, will have a frequency for each count.

My reasoning for Method 2 is that it covers any and all possible 30-minute windows from the historical data, whereas Method 1 is only a subset. Method 2 also has counts that are missed by Method 1 i.e. there have been a few 30-minute windows where there were 9 boxes in Method 2, but not in Method 1. I'm not sure which method is correct/typical for obtaining frequencies for a Poisson process. After analyzing the histograms and CDF plots (shown below), they seem similar...

However, regardless of which window method I use, it doesn't seem that the data (boxes exiting timestamps) satisfies assumption(s) for a Poisson process in the first place. Although the boxes themselves are independent of one another and only one box exits at a time, the number of boxes in a 30-minute interval depends on multiple factors e.g. demand, when production is scheduled, the quantity scheduled (and quantity produced so far), the container type scheduled (some containers hold over 100 parts, so only 1 box exits in 30 minutes, whereas some hold less than 20 parts, so multiple boxes can exit in 30 minutes). There are also many periods without production, so the data is zero-inflated. Thus, the probability of X boxes within **any** 30-minute interval is likely not the same. The "Poisson Goodness of Fit Test" in Minitab fails as well (rejects null hypothesis for Chi-Square test).

So, even if it isn't Poisson, I could still use the empirical distribution (CDF). But this feels wrong, as it does not account for the factors mentioned above. Should I be doing some kind of conditional probability based on scheduling patterns (i.e. when production is scheduled and quantity/containers scheduled)? If so, how can I look at the probability of scheduling patterns based on these timestamps alone? One thought was to use Markov chains (e.g. probability of going from X<sub>1</sub> boxes having N<sub>1</sub> total parts in one 30-minute interval to X<sub>2</sub> boxes having N<sub>2</sub> total parts in the next 30-minute interval)... I'm not really sure what I'm doing / how to proceed.

[image: HistogramsAndCDF]

Comment: Do you have the information about production schedule, or do you need to infer it from the number of boxes? The idea of a (hidden) Markov chain is not completely off :-)

Comment: Start with a good description of *why* you want to make this model. After that one can think about what is (ideally) needed in order to do what you want to do. Currently you are not explaining what you want to do and an answer is difficult to give. For instance, you ask “Should I be doing some kind of conditional probability based on scheduling patterns”, but how are we supposed to know whether you need to be doing this?

Comment: @Ute Unfortunately, no production schedule data. I would have to infer it from the historical box data (timestamps for boxes exiting, parts in each box)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The reason why I want to make this simulation model of the boxes exiting is to identify the best transport mechanisms/strategies for delivering boxes to the warehouse in a 30-minute interval. For example, a worst case scenario would be 9 boxes (as per the histogram), so the transport mechanism may need to be large to hold 9 boxes. But doing some probabilistic analysis, maybe a small transport mechanism for holding 5 boxes will suffice (75% of the time, this seems to be the case as per the CDF) and have an additional strategy for when there are more.

Comment: @user18463824 this makes your question an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You want to optimize the capacity of storage and delivery of boxes, and ask instead for ways to characterise the distribution of the number of boxes per 30 minutes.

Comment: You are not seeing a Poisson-shaped distribution in either chart and so do not have a Poisson process.  But you do have a lot of data (over 10,000 timestamps), so you can see how different transport mechanisms might have performed historically in terms of things that presumably have costs such as size of transport or  numbers of trips or delays in delivery.

Comment: Although I agree that you quite likely can optimize your procedure using the existing data alone, I think it is a nice mathematical / statistical quest to find a good model for such data. The peak for zeros and ones could also come from a mixture of Poisson counts, as you would get them from an inhomogeneous Poisson process. For such an analysis it would be best to keep the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you are asking, estimation of the intensity of boxes, you should use the maximum likelihood estimate. For Poisson process it is simply the ratio of the total number of events (boxes) divided by the total observation time. E.g. if you have 10 boxes produced over two hour the intensity is $5 = 10 / 2$.

Given that you have non-productive time, you can identify it by looking more closely  to your data trying to identify some periodic structure in it.

If you want to model more complex dynamic of your process, you should consider some example from temporal point processes (TPP). For example, you can look at [Hawkes process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkes_process), that says that the conditional intensity of events depends on the frequency of recent past events. You can also include other features that affect the intensity as well. This approach is called Marked TPP.